# How can I make bootstrap menu width as width as the total width of the elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, navbar

I have the following code using the bootstrap menu but I can't seem to get the menu work as I want too.

```
<header class="navbar center-navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-th-list"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse nav-collapse-margin">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>                        
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Content
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="Content1.aspx">Content 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="Content2.aspx">Content 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="More.aspx">More</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The center-navbar looks like

```
.center-navbar
{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

With the code above I get a centered menubar but the menuitems are all to the left and there is a large portion of the menubar that is empty at the right. I want the menu to be centered and just as wide as it needs to be to contain the menuitems.

It looks like this now (but centered on the page)
<--Home--About--Content--More------------>

I want this and still cented on the page
<--Home--About--Content--More-->

I don't want to fiddle around in the bootstrap css but I'm definitly ok with making my own css definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I just done a litle example that you can use to do what you want

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/t68nz/1/

**CSS**

```
.center-navbar
{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav li {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    min-width:200px;
}

one-item{
width: 100%;
}

two-item{
width: 50%;
}

three-item{
width: 33.33%;
}

for-item{
width: 25%;
}
```

then with js code, you had directly the class to all li items

Comment: That only makes the individuell menuitems use the same width in the menu but the menu is still to large.

Comment: I want the menu to be as wide as needed to encapsulate as many menuitems as needed but at most 80% of the screen. If I only have one menuitem the menu should be centered with just one element with two elements the menubar should be centered and the width should be enough to just encapsulate the two menuitems. 

It shouldn't matter how many menu-item there is in the menu the menu should be as wide as needed.

Comment: In this case, you need to use javascript to add different class to your menu. review my modification